# AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split' 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, decode

I need help to fix this code:

```
import urllib.request,urllib.parse,urllib.error
    fhand = urllib.request.urlopen("http://data.pr4e.org//romeo.txt")
    counts = dict ()
    for line in fhand:
        lines = line.decode.split()
        for words in lines:
            counts[words] = counts.get(words,0)+1
    print(counts)
```

I am getting this error while running this code:

```
C:\Users\g.p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32>py urllib2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "urllib2.py", line 5, in <module>
    lines = line.decode.split()
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should run `decode` function, otherwise, it will be the built-in function not `str`, so you cannot `split` the function

You should write like this:

```
lines = line.decode().split()
```

For more info: [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-strings-decode-method/)